# Text Output in Pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame, output

I'm hitting a bit of a wall with a text-based game that I'm working on.

I'm in the process of porting it from a version that works through print-output to a version that runs in a pygame window.

Currently my input works fine, however my output still prints to the console. I was told I should be putting the output into a text buffer, and this could be achieved by changing my print() functions to my_print.

The thing is, I know nothing about using text-buffers.

From what I understand, the point of a text-buffer would be to store the desired output as a variable, which can then be displayed in my pygame window. I'm just not really sure *how* to do this.

I would also preferably like the most recent 5 outputs to display in a sort of "Game Log".

This video helped significantly with figuring out the input, but the output section doesn't seem to be quite what I need.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G933SOLWbbg&t=181s

Here's my code:

display:

```
from pygame_functions import *
import random
screenSize(800, 800)

wordBox = makeTextBox(50, 700, 700, 0, "Enter Command", 0, 24)
showTextBox(wordBox)

gameLog = makeLabel(my_print, 30, 50, 500, "white", "Agency FB", "black" )
showLabel(gameLog)
```

gamefile:

```
from pygame import *
from gameworld import *
from Display import *

def main():

    player = Player("Jeff", 100)
    bag = Bag([])
    location = Location('introd')

    command = '  '
    while True:
        command = textBoxInput(wordBox)
        if command in location.room.exits:
            location.travel(command, bag)
        elif command == 'look':
            location.room_desc()
        elif command == '':
            print('You have to say what it is you want to do!')
            command = '#'
        elif command == 'search':
            location.search_room()
        elif command.split()[0] == 'Take':
            location.check_take(command.split()[1], bag, location)
        elif command == 'Inventory':
            bag.check_inv()
        else:
            print('Invalid command')
        if not command:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

gameworld:

```
from gameitems import *


class Room:

    def __init__(self, name, description, exits, actions, roominv, roomkey, lock):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.exits = exits
        self.actions = actions
        self.roominv = roominv
        self.roomkey = roomkey
        self.lock = lock


class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health


class Location:

    def __init__(self, room):
        self.room = world[room]

    def travel(self, direction, bag):
        if direction not in self.room.exits:
            self.no_exit()
        else:
            self.set_new_room_name(direction, bag)

    def set_new_room_name(self, direction, bag):
        new_room_name = self.room.exits[direction]
        print("moving to", new_room_name)
        self.key_check(new_room_name, bag)

    def key_check(self, new_room_name, bag):
        if world[new_room_name].lock and world[new_room_name].roomkey not in bag.inventory:
            self.no_key()
        else:
            world[new_room_name].lock = False
            self.set_room(new_room_name)
            self.room_desc()

    def set_room(self, new_room_name):
        self.room = world[new_room_name]

    def no_exit(self):
        print("You can't go that way!")

    def no_key(self):
        print('The door is locked! You need the right key!')

    def room_desc(self):
        print(self.room.description)
        print(self.room.actions)

    def search_room(self):
        if self.room.roominv:
            for item in list(self.room.roominv.keys()):
                print("you find a", item)
        else:
            print("You don't find anything")

    def none_here(self, key):
        print("You can't find a", key)

    def check_take(self, key, bag, location):
        if key in self.room.roominv:
            bag.add_to_inv(key, location)
            print('you take the', key)
        else:
            self.none_here(key)


class Bag():

    def __init__(self, inventory):
        self.inventory = inventory

    def add_to_inv(self, key, location):
        self.inventory.append(location.room.roominv[key])
        del location.room.roominv[key]

    def check_inv(self):
        for item in self.inventory:
            print("Your bag contains:", item.name)


world = {}

world['introd'] = Room('introd', "You are in a forest, you can hear wildlife all around you. There seems to be a clearing in the distance.", {'n': "clearing"}, {"Search the ground", "Go North"}, {'Sword': Sword}, None, False)

world['clearing'] = Room('clearing', "You are in a clearing surrounded by forest. Sunlight is streaming in, illuminating a bright white flower in the center of the clearing. \
To the South is the way you entered the forest. A well worn path goes to the East. In the distance a harp can be heard.", {'s': "introd", 'e': "forest path"}, {"Take flower", "Go south", "Go East"}, {'Flower': Flower}, None, False)

world['forest path'] = Room('forest path', "You begin walking down a well beaten path. The sounds of the forest surround you. Ahead you can see a fork in the road branching to the South and East.\
You can smell smoke coming from the South, and can hear a stream to the East", {'s': "cottage", 'e': "stream", 'w': "clearing"}, {"Go South", "Go East", "Go West"}, {'Stick': Stick}, None, False)

world['stream'] = Room('stream', "You come upon a relaxing stream at the edge of the woods. It looks like there is something shiny in the water. To your South is a rickety looking shack, \
to your West is the forest path you came down", {'s': "shack", 'w': "forest path"}, {"Go South", "Go West"}, {'Rusty_Key': Rusty_Key}, None, False)

world['shack'] = Room('shack', "In front of you is a shack, possibly used as an outpost for hunting. It looks dilapidated.", {'s': "inside shack", 'n': "stream"}, {"Go South", "Go North"}, None, None, False)

world['inside shack'] = Room('inside shack', "The inside of the shack is dirty. Bits of ragged fur are scattered about the floor and on a table against the back wall.\
A sharp looking knife is on the table. There is an ornate key hanging on the wall by a string.", {'n': "shack"}, {"Go North", "Take Knife", "Take Key"}, {'Knife': Knife, 'Ornate_Key': Ornate_Key}, Rusty_Key, True)

world['cottage'] = Room('cottage', "A quaint cottage sits in the middle of a small clearing, smoke drifting lazily from the chimney.", {'n': "forest path"}, {"Go north"}, None, None, False)

world['inside cottage'] = Room('inside cottage', "The inside of the cottage is warm and cozy. It reeks like death.", {'n': 'outside cottage'}, None, {'Moonstone': Moonstone}, Ornate_Key, True)
```

gameitems:

```
class Items:
    def __init__(self, name, info, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        self.weight = weight


class DoorKeys(Items):
    def __init__(self, name, info, weight):
        super().__init__(name, info, weight)


class Weapon(Items):
    def __init__(self, name, info, damage, speed, weight):
        super().__init__(name, info, weight)
        self.damage = damage
        self.speed = speed


Sword = Weapon("Sword", "A sharp looking sword. Good for fighting goblins!", 7, 5, 5)
Knife = Weapon("Knife", "A wicked looking knife, seems sharp!", 5, 7, 3)
Stick = Weapon("Stick", "You could probably hit someone with this stick if you needed to", 2, 3, 3)
Rusty_Key = DoorKeys("Rusty_Key", "A key! I wonder what it opens.", .01)
Ornate_Key = DoorKeys("Ornate_Key", "An ornate key with an engraving of a small cottage on one side", .01)
Moonstone = Items("Moonstone", "A smooth white stone that seems to radiate soft white light", .05)
Flower = Items("Flower", "A beautiful wildflower", .001)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they mean by a *Text Buffer* is just a fancy term of creating a *Font Object*.

First you would generate a font object using `pygame.font.Font`

```
myFont = pygame.font.Font('MyFontFile.ttf', MySize)
```

And then you would render it using `Font.render`

```
myText = myFont.render('myText', True, MyColor)
```

Finnaly, you would blit it onto the screen.

```
myScreen.blit(myText, (0, 0))
```

With a project as complex as yours and the stuff you want though, you might want to create a full text object that inherits the font object

```
class AdvancedFont(pygame.font.Font):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

It could have scrolling capabilities, colors, whatever you would like!

Also, on youre next question, try cutting down the example code some until we can get something slightly more testable.

Comment: So, I understand that I can use this to render a specific message onto the screen, but it's unclear to me how I can adapt this to replace my print functions. Can you elaborate at all?

Comment: Sure! What you can do is change the print statements and instead just add text objects into a list. Afterwards, loop through the list and then draw the text, when the list exceeds a length of 5, knock off the first text object in the list. this would allow the log you wanted.